# php fpm on ubuntu 14 throwing Service Unavailable

Tags: php, linux

I ran this following command to find out which port is being occupied by php-fpm

```
 netstat -pl | grep fpm
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9500     -                   /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

I have this following proxypassmatch in my web configuration file

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.php.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9500/var/www/html/$1 timeout=1800
```

I have all the necessary dependencies installed for processing php fpm as a fastcgi module.

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
        Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
        Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
                SetHandler fastcgi-script
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

My VirtualHost directives are in the following set:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/ec1ed7d470bd0db4.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/.crt
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dir

  # Setup php-fpm to process php files
  # ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9500/var/www/html/dir/$1
  # ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.php.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9500/var/www/html/$1 timeout=1800
</VirtualHost>
```

I still get the following message after restarting Apache and php fpm

```
Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems
```

Comment: Your php is configured to listen for a file socket not a network socket.

Comment: Does this mean I should change fcgi://127.0.0.1:9500 to another port?

Comment: It means that `9500` is not a tcp port at all :-D Check https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM#unix_domain_socket_.28UDS.29_approach Also run `netstat -pl` without grep and see how file sockets and tcp sockets are different.